# Boolean cast Specified cast is not valid error - Passing value from a case statement to a reader.GetBooleanVal

Tags: c#, sql

The error that I'm getting when I hit the `item.FinancialHold` when I'm going through my loop of `reader.GetBooleanVal` is  "specified cast is not valid."  But everything seem to be correct on my select statement. Not sure why I'm getting this exception.

My goal was depending of a certain value that I'm returning I'm changing the results of another column, reason why I'm using a case statement... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 List<CollectionCodeParameter> list = new List<CollectionCodeParameter>();
        var sql = @"IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.[collcode_Agency_Codes])
            BEGIN
                select
                  [collcode],
                   case when([collcode] = 'PIE')  then 1
                else 0
               end as [fin_hold],
                 FROM[dbo].[collcode_Agency_Codes]
            WITH(NOLOCK)
      WHERE type = @AgencyType
            END";
          ....code....

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var ordinals = reader.GetOrdinals();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                CollectionCodeParameter item = new CollectionCodeParameter();

                item.FinancialHold = reader.GetBooleanVal(ordinals.GetOrdinal("fin_hold")).HasValue ? 
                reader.GetBooleanVal(ordinals.GetOrdinal("fin_hold")).Value : false; ;


                list.Add(item);
            }
```

The error is coming from below. My fin_hold is a bit in my table definitions.

```
public static bool? GetBooleanVal(this SqlDataReader reader, int ordinal)
    {
        if (ordinal < 0) return null;
        return reader.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? null : (bool?)reader.GetBoolean(ordinal);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help you debugging to resolve the if statement you cut short, so you can debug it line for line.

I can't try the SQL right now, so I have to guess:
In your SQL, your case-statement is not returning `bit` , but an `int`.

```
case when([collcode] = 'PIE')
    then 1
    else 0
end as [fin_hold],
```

Edit:

> My fin_hold is a bit in my table definitions.

You are not returning your column, but a number from your case-statement. The alias `as [fin_hold]` does not relate to your table definition.

Try this:

```
case when([collcode] = 'PIE')
    then Cast(1 as bit)
    else Cast(0 as bit)
end as [fin_hold],
```